# Webkit css warning diagnosis

Tags: css, webkit

Im trying to do a webkit css3 transition however when the link becomes a:visited the transition no longer functions and the webkit inspector would give me the following

[image: Screen Shot]

How would I diagnose what the alert triangle says, the console is empty in all areas (All, Warnings.. etc).

It only happens when the link is visited

Comment: Because `transition` is not formalized as part of the CSS3 specifications yet Webkit uses the `-webkit-transition` property and ignores the "standard" `transition` property. This is normal, and the warning doesn't mean anything except that the property is ignored. You'll have to provide more information (like the code you're using) for us to help you.

Comment: I see. The issue was the transition didn't work so I thought it was the triangle. I think browsers don't support css transitions on a:visited links https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means there is something wrong with the property or its value (or, that it's unrecognized).

See [what does the yellow color warning icon mean in the chrome web inspector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981782/what-does-the-yellow-color-warning-icon-mean-in-the-chrome-web-inspector)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a bug. Check out [this chromium issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101245&q=visited%20transition&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary#makechanges)