# Is the background-image overwritten or are missing css files the reason?

Tags: css

After inspecting the page, I found out that the **background-image** is kind of overridden:

[image]

But I couldn't find any statement that could have overwritten it.

Could the missing CSS files be the source of the problem with the **background-image**?

Comment: it means that the property is invalid not overwritten (don't know why ..)

Comment: It should be `hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0)` - the second value, saturation, is a percentage. The little warning icon means that the value the browser found for that property is invalid.

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981782/what-does-the-yellow-color-warning-icon-mean-in-the-chrome-web-inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using HSLA incorrectly, please refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) for the syntax of HSLA.
This should work.

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #404040, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

your CSS attribute (hsla) was wrong, that's why it's not taking.

The hsla() function define colors using the Hue-saturation-lightness-alpha model (HSLA).

**css syntax:**    **hsla(hue, saturation, lightness, alpha)**

background-image: **linear-gradient(180deg, #404040, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0));**

more examples:

p1 {background-color:hsla(120,100%,50%,0.3);} /* green */

p2 {background-color:hsla(120,100%,75%,0.3);} /* light green */

p3 {background-color:hsla(120,100%,25%,0.3);} /* dark green */

p4 {background-color:hsla(120,60%,70%,0.3);} /* pastel green */